# How modal dialog is implemented?

Tags: user-interface

For a long time I have been wondering how modal dialog is implemented.

Let me take Qt as an example. (Nearly all GUI toolkit has this mechanism)

In the main event loop, a slot is called, and in this slot a modal dialog is opened. Before the dialog is closed, the slot doesn't return control to the main event loop. So I thought that the main event loop is blocked and become unresponsive. Apparently this is not true, since when you open a modal dialog, the background main window is still working, like repainting its UI or keep displaying a curve or some graph. It just becomes not to accept any user input.

I did an experiment. I didn't open a modal dialog in the slot, but start a new thread there, and wait for the thread to finish in that slot. This definitely blocked the main event loop.

How modal dialog is implemented after all? How does it keep main event loop unblocked but at the same time blocked the calling slot?

Comment: FYI for readers, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26741841/10027592) for Win32API. At least in Win32API(and MFC), which is basically a single-threaded GUI, the modal dialog spawns a "nested" message loop, and it works like a nested for loop - so it actually kinda "blocks" during its iterating, but it can invoke DispatchMessage which in turn invokes the corresponding WndProc or other message handlers, so those tasks such as the background repainting can be done even while the modal dialog's message loop is iterating.

Answer (score 3):

There is only ever a need for a single event loop, and it does *not* block when a modal dialog appears. Though, I suppose, different toolkits may handle this differently. You would need to consult the documentation to know for sure. Conceptually, however, it all works in the same way.

Every event has a source where the event occured. When a modal dialog appears, the event loop either ignores or redirects all events that originate outside of the dialog. There's really no magic to it. Generally speaking, it's like an if statement in the event loop code that says "if (modal_is_shown() and !event_is_in_modal_window()) {ignore_and_wait_for_next_event()}". Of course, the logic is a bit more complicated, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for examples here's another one:

In Tk, there is only ever one event loop. Modal behavior (doesn't have to be dialog, can also be tooltips, textbox etc) is simply implemented by making the main window ignore mouse and keyboard events. All other events like redraws etc. can still be serviced because the event loop is still running.

Tk implements this via the `[grab]` function. Calling `grab` on a UI object makes it the only object able to respond to keyboard and mouse events. Essentially blocking all other objects. This doesn't mess with the event loop. It merely temporarily disables event handlers until the grab is released.

It should be noted that Unix-like operating systems running X also has `grab` built in to the windowing system. So it's not necessarily implemented merely by UI toolkit libraries but is sometimes also a built in feature of the OS. Again, this is implemented by simple blocking/disabling of events instead of instantiating separate event loops. I believe this also used to be the case for the older MacOS before OSX. Not sure about OSX or Windows though. Even though modality is often implemented by the OS itself, toolkits like Qt and Tk often implement their own mechanisms to standardize behaviors across different platforms.

So the conclusion is, it is not necessary to block the main event loop to implement modality. You just need to block the events and/or event handlers.

Comment: Interesting. If come back to my specific question, could you tell me if the main event loop is blocked when the modal dialog is opened? My test shows that the main event block is NOT blocked, but the modal dialog calling slot is not returned, so the main event loop should be blocked at the time. This is conflicting with each other.

Comment: Don't know about Qt I'm afraid so the terms you use like "slots" sounds alien to me. But if, as you say, the main event loop is not blocked then it sounds like it implements it in a similar way to Tk.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill is correct.

However, reading the follow-up discussion between him and https://stackoverflow.com/users/188326/solotim , I feel that there is room for further clarification, by means of prose and some pseudo-code.

I'll handle the prose part with a fact-list:

- The main message loop does not run until the modal activity is finished
- However, events are still delivered while the modal activity is running
- This is because there is a **nested event loop** within the modal activity.

So far I just repeated Greg's answer, please bear with me as it is for continuity's sake. Below is where I hope to contribute additional, useful info.

- The nested event loop is part of the GUI toolkit, and as such, it knows the callback functions related to every window in existence
- When the nested event loop raises an event (such as a repaint event directed to the main window), it invokes the callback function associated with that event. *Note that "callback" here may refer to a method of a class representing a window, in object-oriented systems.*
- the callback function does what is needed (e.g., repaint), and returns right back to the nested message loop (the one within the modal activity)

Last, but not least, here's pseudo-code to hopefully illustrate further, using a fictitious "GuiToolkit":

```
void GuiToolkit::RunModal( ModalWindow *m )
{
    // modal (nested) event loop
    while( !GuiToolkit::IsFinished() && m->IsOpen() )
    {
          GuiToolkit::ProcessEvent(); // this will call
                                      // MainWindow::OnRepaint
                                      // as needed, via the virtual
                                      // method of the base class
                                      // NonModalWindow::OnRepaint
    }
}

class AboutDialog: public ModalWindow
{
}

class MainWindow: public NonModalWindow
{
    virtual void OnRepaint()
    {
        ...
    }
    virtual void OnAboutBox()
    {
         AboutDialog about;
         GuiToolkit::RunModal(&about); // blocks here!!
    }
}

main()
{
    MainWindow window;
    GuiToolkit::Register( &window ) // GuiToolkit knows how to 
                                    // invoke methods of window

    // main event loop
    while( !GuiToolkit::IsFinished() )
    {
          GuiToolkit::ProcessEvent(); // this will call
                                      // MainWindow::OnAboutBox
                                      // at some point
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, I think Windows(Win32API) works this way. (I'm not sure if this applies to Unix-like OSs, too). Btw, I think the code comment should be `// nested event loop` in the `GuiToolkit::RunModal`, not main event loop :)

Comment: Good catch on the comment, fixed!  And glad that someone read this and kept me honest :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, a modal dialog box of this type is implemented by running its *own* message loop instead of your application's message loop. Messages directed to your main window (such as timer or paint messages) will still get delivered, even during the modal operation.

In some situations, you may have to be careful that you don't recursively do the same thing repeatedly. For example, if you trigger a modal dialog box on a timer message combined with some persistent flag, you'll want to make sure you don't keep bringing up the same dialog box repeatedly whenever the timer message fires.

Comment: yes the messages will still be delivered, but how the main event loop get a chance to "handle" them. I mean is the main event loop blocked or not when the slot is not returned (the slot is waiting for the modal dialog)?

Comment: You'll probably find that the main message loop does *not* handle messages during the time the modal dialog is visible. In that case messages are handled by a *different* message loop inside the modal dialog code.

Comment: Are you sure the message loop inside the modal dialog will handle all messages directed to the main window? For example, when you drag and move the modal dialog, the background window will repaint/redraw some area, is it handled by the modal dialog? I can't understand that.

Comment: The repaint *message* is received by the message loop inside the modal dialog, and then the message is dispatched to the main window using the usual message dispatcher. The modal dialog does not need to know how to paint the main window.

Comment: Thanks Greg. But let's come back to the "blocking" part. Is main event loop blocked or not while the modal dialog is opening? If it's blocked, although somehow the message is dispatched to it by modal dialog's message loop, it doesn't have a chance to really handle it. If it's not blocked, the slot is not returned, how it becomes not blocked?

Comment: Yes, the main message loop is blocked. But that's not the only possible message loop. To test this yourself, put some debug logging code in your main message loop, and see when it runs and when it doesn't.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19619/discussion-between-solotim-and-greg-hewgill)

Comment: @GregHewgill Is this answer about Windows(Win32API / MFC) specifically? I'm asking because two other answers only talk about *one* event loop (although this can be different depending on OS/framework).