# How does a modal dialog's message-pump interact with the main application message-pump?

Tags: winapi, mfc

My understanding is any modal dialog automatically has its own message-pump, running on a thread dedicated to that dialog - is that right?

If so, how does a modal dialog's existence affect the main application's message loop? Do both run in parallel, does one take priority?

I have a situation where a modal dialog seems to get stuck for several seconds waiting for something, and wondered if it's possible the dialog is forced to wait until the main application thread is not busy?

Comment: They run on the same thread. The modal dialog spawns a *nested message loop*. Both the nested message loop and the main application's message loop (or rather message handlers) are siamese twins in crime: If one doesn't play by the rules, the respective other will suffer as well.

Comment: So will the calling thread's message loop still be running as normal, or does it get suspended somehow?

Comment: There is only one thread involved. When the modal dialog's nested message loop runs, it dispatches all incoming messages. If the dialog performs operations that result in sending messages for the main application to handle, that call will not return until the message handler is done. All message handling is serialized (it runs on a single thread) - if a message handler takes a long time to run to completion, nothing else will run on that thread. Regardless of whether it is the modal dialog or any other application window.

Comment: So like a nested while() loop then - the primary message loop just stops and waits for the dialog's message loop to terminate before carrying on? The main WndProc simply will not get called while the modal dialog is active?

Comment: (After discussing with jamesdlin) For begginers like me, let me answer @Mr.Boy's comment: **1)** *"So like a nested while loop the primary message loop just stops..."* ->Yes. **2)** "The main WndProc simply will not get called while..." ->There is no "main" WndProc. The modal dialog's nested message loop will call `DispatchMessage`, which will directly call the `WndProc` of the recipient window. And the dialog's nested message loop is halted until that `WndProc` finishes handling that message and returns.

Comment: (...continued) After the `WndProc` returns, the nested message loop will continue iterating (unless the loop was broken by dismissing the dialog). When the dialog's nested message loop finishes spinning(when the dialog box is closed), only then does the main message loop resume spinning. Note that `DispatchMessage` "directly calls" the WndProc(or other message handlers), rather than "sending" the message to another message queue/loop. - Maybe that's why it was named *Dispatch*Message, not SendMessage. (Many thanks to jamesdlin for discussing with me)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As IInspectable explained, the modal dialog will run in the same thread as the caller.  Therefore if you run the dialog from the main UI thread that has your main message loop, you'll end up with a nested message loop.  The stack would look something like:

```
WinMain
    YourMainMessageLoop
        DispatchMessage
            SomeMessageHandler
                DoModal
```

and `DoModal` spins in its own `GetMessage`/`TranslateMessage`/`DispatchMessage` loop.  The main message loop (`YourMainMessageLoop` in the sample stack above) is "active" in the sense that it's still running, but it's *blocked* by the dialog's message loop.  Execution won't return to `YourMainMessageLoop` until `DoModal` exits.

Note that even if you're within the modal dialog's message loop, your other windows will still handle messages because `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage` will still retrieve and direct messages to those windows and invoke their `WndProc`s.

Comment: "your other windows will still get messages because `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage`..." but those are called by _the dialog's_ message loop, right? Basically it takes over the boring "keep the application working" stuff.

Comment: @Mr.Boy Yes, they're invoked by the dialog's message loop.  Note that `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage` don't know which message loop they're being called from.  It's all the same to them.

Comment: If `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage` forward messages to other windows, how is that **modal**? I thought **modal** implies that users must interact with that window first before they can interact with other UI.

Comment: @David You should distinguish between [UI modality and code modality](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050218-00/?p=36413).  A UI-modal dialog does not prevent other windows from receiving window messages (otherwise those windows wouldn't be able to paint or do various other things), but those windows will still be disabled and won't allow the user to interact with them.

Comment: Is there a way to internally interfere with the `DoModal` in this example? Like adding some other function in its message procession or making it skip some sort of messages?

Comment: @user814412 You could install a `WM_GETMESSAGE` hook, but that's rather heavyweight and is not something I'd recommend lightly.

Comment: you said, "the main message loop is *blocked* by the dialog's message loop". Then, how is it possible for the main message loop to handle other messages? E.g. even if a modal dialog box is shown to the user, other visible areas of the program repaint or handle messages I think. (although not receiving the user's input)

Comment: @starriet This has already been explained in the comments.  The main message loop is not handling messages; the dialog's nested message loop is by calling `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks! But still didn't understand. If only *one thread* is running and the dialog's nested msg loop is spinning, how can the message dispatched from the dialog to the main window be handled? Shouldn't it be blocked until the dialog's nested msg loop finishes spinning? (e.g. repaint the background, etc.)

Comment: @starriet `DispatchMessage` dispatches the message.  This means that it determines which `HWND` the message is for and invokes its corresponding `WndProc` with the message.  In general, each window has an associated `WndProc` that is responsible for handling its own messages.  The presence of a nested message loop only changes which message loop is passing the message to the `WndProc`, and the originating message loop shouldn't matter.

Comment: Could you correct me once again? You said only *one* thread is working. My understanding is: If just one thread is involved, the main message loop and the dialog's nested message loop should spin *together* (**not** like a nested for loop). If it's not, how can one thread run both dialog's nested message loop *and* msg handlers outside of the nested msg loop? Or, each `WndProc` of each window runs its *own* thread? Even so, my above understanding applies if we consider only one window and one `WndProc`. Please correct me if I'm wrong, thanks again! :)

Comment: @starriet The nested message loop and main message loop do not spin together.  The nested message loop runs and blocks the main message loop from iterating again, exactly like a nested `for` loop.  There are no extra threads; `DispatchMessage` is simply invoking function pointers in the current thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247862/discussion-between-jamesdlin-and-starriet).