# Using SendMessage to get data between two modal dialogs

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741841/how-does-a-modal-dialogs-message-pump-interact-with-the-main-application-messag) and am trying to get my head around something.

I have `CDialog1` and `CDialog2`.

The former (model dialog) displays the latter (model dialog).

Whist `CDialog2` is displayed, is it ok to Use `SendMessage` to extract some info from the parent (`CDialog1`) parent?

Comment: If you have all the code, and the data is not changed over time, then why not just give the data to CDialog2 before creating it?

Comment: @Dialecticus Sure, I’ll do it that way.